# React Native, route.params giving an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'am having an error while using `route.params` in React Native. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
{console.log("==========Test Home Nav==========", route)}
Output {key: "123", name: "Home", params: {"cartCount": 32} // It is Fine

{console.log("==========Test Home Nav==========", route.params.cartCount)}  // Error occur
```

This is the hole code :

[image]
How to fix this error please ? Thank you.

Comment: Use it ```route.params[cartCount]```

Comment: Can you show what error you get?